# Why all the text in my site is in upper case

Tags: javascript, html, css

I downloaded some free web templates and updating the site as per my needs. I observed most of site content is displayed in upper case. Can someone help me, how to disable this?
Attached is the screenshot of the page. All links and content is displayed in uppercase.

How to display this in normal case letters?

[image]

Following is my html before body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Freee-Learn. Your learning partner...</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Custom Theme files -->
        <!--theme-style-->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />  
        <!--//theme-style-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Free Style Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
        <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <!--fonts-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:100,300,400,500,700,800,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic,800italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--//fonts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myJavaScript.js"></script>
        <!-- start menu -->
        <script src="js/simpleCart.min.js"> </script>
        <link href="css/memenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/memenu.js"></script>
        <script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".memenu").memenu();});</script>
    </head>
```

**And also i observed, when the internet is off, the site is displayed in normal case letters.**

Comment: that's not uppercase. that's smallcaps. and probably one or more of your style sheets is fulling in a style which forces smallcaps. use your dom inspector to see where the smallcaps rule is coming from

Comment: That's not "all caps", it looks like a font that has "small caps", i.e. the "lowercase" code points are rendered as slightly smaller versions of the uppercase letters.  When you are not connected it cannot access the web font and renders with a default font that has real lowercase characters.

Comment: Looks like the google font Alegreya is causing this https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Alegreya+Sans+SC

Comment: @UglyCode - Post that as an answer and I'll +1 it

Comment: Check your source in developer view and target any paragraph. Check the CSS tab and scroll down until you find the declaration where you are declaring small caps. Remove it from the CSS.

Comment: @StevenMoseley Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's the fonts that you're using in the website. The fonts are downloaded from an Google API. Download the fonts to use locally or use another font.

Comment: Removed the below 2 lines and working fine. <!--fonts-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:100,300,400,500,700,800,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic,800italic,900italic' 

rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--//fonts-->

Answer (score 2):

One of the [web fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Alegreya+Sans+SC) you're leveraging (`Alegreya Sans SC`) is only available as a small caps family. When your "internet is off", the web font is not being loaded and therefore a default family is leveraged which most likely supports lower case.

To fix this, find where you're using `Alegreya Sans SC` within your stylesheets and simply switch to a more multi-case friendly family.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the google font Alegreya is causing this google.com/fonts/specimen/Alegreya+Sans+SC